# Adding subviews programmatically positions them weirdly

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a view in which I want to add multiple subviews, however when I add them, they get positioned in positions where I didn't set the frame. The `x` coordinate is correct, but the `y` is quite off.

Using the Interface Builder it went quite smooth, just drag them in and send the correct frame and origin. However I don't appear to be able to set the origin; I get `expression is not assignable` when I try `view.frame.origin = CGPointMake(x, y)`, and setting the `x` and `y` coordinates directly gives me the same error.

Does this happens because subviews cannot overlap programmatically without setting a special attribute (that I'm missing)?

Edit: The views are being set in the `initWithStyle` method of a UITableViewCell.

Edit 2: Added code within `initWithStyle` method.

```
// Initialize images
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
self.anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"]];
self.anotherImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anotherImage"]];

// Set imageview locations
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 54);
self.anImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 53, 16, 52);
self.anotherImageView.frame = CGRectMake(179, 43, 111, 53);
```

Comment: Its hard to tell where its going wrong from just that code. Are you adding those views to your cell? ([cell.contentView addSubview:view])? I know that you should definitely be setting the frames in layoutSubviews.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling `[self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView]` in the  `layoutSubview` methods, but the imageviews are positioned horizontally next to each other when possible, however, the big image (i.e. `self.imageView`) pushes the other imageViews downwards, as if the space could only be occupied by a single imageview.

Comment: I would do the addSubview in the init method, so that you are only adding them once (layout subviews is called multiple times). I guess I don't really understand what's happening without seeing it. Screen shots of what you are seeing based on the frames you listed above could help

Answer (score 3):

To avoid `expression is not assignable`, you have to set the entire frame at once, either using

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
```

or

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = newX;
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. I totally misunderstood the origin attribute. I thought it was like the interface builder where I set the origin to something like top-left or bottom-right. I'm already using `CGRectMake` for the purpose you mentioned. I thought that it would automagically be something like that if I set the origin to the bottom-left of the view, but that was rather silly of me.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are setting the frames in the `viewDidLoad` method. The problem here is that you are setting the frame before the viewControllers frame has been resized based on the constraints of the app.

Try moving your frame setting into the method `viewWillAppear` and see if that fixes your problem.

Edit: Because you are doing this in a cell, and not in a viewController you would do something like the following:

In `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        self.customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Then override `layoutSubviews` to actually set the views frame

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{  
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.customView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
}
```

As far as the "expression is not assignable" warning, this is because you cannot just set a views origin without setting the height and width. Use:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

If you want to keep the same width and height without having to hard code it do something like

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: I'm using the `initWithStyle` method of a UITableViewCell. Is there a special cell method that acts like `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same problem, although I haven't tried it with a custom view yet. Is it not possible inside the contentView?

Comment: Where are you creating the views you are trying to set the frame for? Is this from interface builder or are you creating the views in the initWithStyle method?

Comment: All views are created in `initWithStyle`. I tried to move this to `layoutSubviews` with no success.